# Python3 multiprocessing multiple dependent

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I need to run two consecutive pool.maps in python. But the second one is dependent on the results of the first map. Thus, before running the second pool.map I need to make sure the function1 is executed for all args. Can anyone show me how to do that?

```
    # The first multiprocessing unit
    pool = Pool(processes=num_p)
    new_args=dict(pool.map(function1, args))

    # The second multiprocessing unit
    pool.map(function2, new_args)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Surely `pool.map` will block until the results are done. How else could it return them?

You can also confirm this fact from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).

> It blocks until the result is ready.